# How to get rid of erroneous extra grid lines?

Tags: tables, grid-typesetting

**The below code is giving me an error:**

How do I get rid of these bad extra lines? See image at the bottom.

```
\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|r|r|r|r|r|}

\hline

\multicolumn{1}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|}{$x$} &
\multicolumn{1}{ >{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|}{\textbf{Actual}} &
\multicolumn{1}{ >{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|}{\textbf{Approx.}} &
\multicolumn{1}{ >{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|}{\textbf{\% diff}} &
\multicolumn{1}{ >{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|}{\textbf{\% grow}} 

\\

\hline

2 & 1.0000 & 0.5576 & -44.2\% & 0.0\% \\ \hline
3 & 2.0000 & 1.4943 & -25.3\% & 168.0\% \\ \hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:
[image]

Another error:
[image]

Comment: Please always post full, but minimal, compilable example code. Here the preamble is missing and other users can't compile it to test out their solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

error due to tabularx which requires a X type column

convert tabularx to tabular

delete linewidth command

misscellaneous --use rowcolor instead of columncolor

Comment: thank you so much, let me try those.

Comment: Now, how do I left align the table?

Comment: use \noindent and hspace{-3cm}

Comment: thank you again, where do I put that?

Comment: above begintabular

Comment: let me try, thanks

Comment: Hi js, how do I add another table with the very same code? I tried to do that, but it doesn't come after a line I added with text, it creates the other table before the text line!! How I hate latex.

Comment: Please see the image I added.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured this.